# How to disable asking for root password while ejecting USB drives?

Tags: udev, usb-drive, flash-memory, udisks

When I mount usb drive it mounts successfully, but when I hit triangle button in Thunar (Eject) - I'm asked for root password! Executing `$ udisks --eject /dev/sdd` in console doesn't require root password. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Udisks, which automatically mounts your devices and doesn't ask you root password, uses udev. You need to clear query database for your usb drive, just execute `sudo udevadm info -c /dev/sdd`

PS additional commands to manage usb mount ing you may find via `man -k udev` and `man -k udisk`